# Facebook like-box not refreshing page on like

Tags: .net, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-graph-api

In my application i use for Facebook like-box plugin:

```
<div class="likedialog" title="Like">
    <div>
       <fb:like-box href="@ViewBag.PageLink" width="370" height="72" show_faces="false"      stream="false" header="false"></fb:like-box>
        </div>
     </div>
```

The problem is: this like is not refreshing page after like click. 
I use for subscribe event in my js file:

```
window.FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function (response) {
        top.location.href = response + "?sk=app_" + window.AppId;
    }
);
```

But this event not fire.
Somebody can tell me what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

Without any error message, we can only guess.

First, use this code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

Second: Check the Browser console for errors and check if the edge event even gets called. Did you initialize the JavaScript SDK? Else, you cannot use "FB".

You need this one (replace the xxxxxx with your App ID):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Also, don´t forget the namespace:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

Btw, there seems to be a bug with this: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/378710432185222/

Comment: Facebook SDK initialized. My application is Facebook app, is full Facebook API app and don't work without initialize Facebook all.js. My problem with "edge.create" subscribe is not a new problem. I found same problems with Facebook API in past many times, but still can't get good question what we can do with this...

Comment: replace "windows.FB" with "FB", for example. always use the example code. then remove the code line in the callback function and just use alert or console.log to test if you even reach the callback.